# Какая опция в tsconfig.json отвечает за типизацию this в объектах?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Почему `this` имеет тип `any` в следующем примере?

```
const x = {
  name: 'x',
  getX() {
    // this почему то any
    this.name;
  },
};
```

Проект сгенерирован через nest cli `nest new`

Версии пакетов:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
"@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Потому что x не класс

Comment: @eri не понял ответ. Он типизируется на 100%, знать бы какое свойство за это отвичает, не разу такого не видел что бы this был any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ предназначен для тех, кто пользуется редакторами кода (IDE) от Microsoft:

- VS Code
- Visual Studio

Есть ощущение, что `this` не будет иметь тип `any` в иных редакторах кода / IDE. Буду признателен тем людям, которые проверят и на других IDE (JetBrains’ WebStorm, IntelliJ IDEA).

---

Необходимо выставить опцию ["strict": true](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    // ... остальные опции
  }
}
```

Мне не удалось найти никакого упоминания о влиянии этой опции на определение типа `this` из контекста кода, поэтому склоняюсь к тому, что такая проблема встречается не во всех редакторах кода и не связана с настройками typescript компилятора.

Comment: спасибо, оно самое.